# Opsworks: chef recipe before shutdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have a ruby on rails layer on Amazon Opsworks and I want to remove an instance from another loadbalancer before the shutdown of the rails server and the machine. It's there a way to have a hook or run a recipe before shutdown stage without creating a custom layer?

Comment: A hook to launch chef-client with specific recipe/json data at inside rc6.d ? (Just a guess on a linux way, I'm not used to OpsWorks )

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if that is going to work, because I need to unlink the instance from the loadbalancer before the unicorn and ngninx get stopped (or I will get downtime untill the health check fail). The problem is because if I use a custom recipe on shutdown phase is runned after all the "rails shutdown" recipes of Opsworks (so I get downtime)